# send data with service every 30seconds in android studio

Tags: android, web-services, android-studio, service

Sorry for my english..:(

I already make a script service android for send data with api every 30 seconds. But I have a problems when I installed to my devices (My devices is xiaomi redmi note2). My service suddenly close about 3-4 minutes.. but I found the problem.I have to setting `Manage apps battery usage-->turn Off restrict background activities`.

for expert please give me suggest or solution about my problem. I want to send data with service without `turn off restrict background activities`.Thank you all.

Comment: Problem is with background service limitation. Try for JobSchedular.

Comment: mr @VVB.. can you give a example for Jibschedular?? thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two the main reason to restrict your background services mainly one is battery uses and another one is android os **DOZE** mode which device have os version greater than equal to 6.0 they all have **DOZE** mode which introduces by android os for battery optimization,

For the solution, you need to use foreground services which not restrict your uses. you can read more about foreground service from the android official document, https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html